Report writing in Project Management
Whenever I apply for a project manager Role, report writing is among the top skills listed..can someone help me demystify what report writing skills are needed in PM?

What do you find mystifying about it? Did you read some projects reports and didn't understand them? Did you look at a bunch of templates online? The question as stated seems very broad as is.

I think that Project Management Stack Exchange is a more suitable place to ask about this (but to be clear, right now you haven't really asked a question).

Generally, when writing a report, you summarize the status or progress of the project, the bugs, the outstanding issues, the roadblocks, the risks to miss the deadline, man power issues, and the potential steps you would take to address these issues, etc... The report also depends on who the audiences or receivers are. It is a skill you learn as you go. If you google your questions, you can find some good answers as the starting points.

Project Managers are not SMEs (Subject Matter Experts). Their jobs are to track all the pieces of job and help overcome impediments. Communication is very important to that role. That report writing skills doesn't pop out at you is somewhat of a red flag. It doesn't mean you can't be a project manager if you want. Just don't peter principle yourself. Get a good understanding of what the role is. It is more about herding cats and keeping everyone updated about the status than anything else. FYI - The absolute best project manage I worked with knew nothing about the how to accomplish the tasks.

Managing a project includes being able to clearly, concisely, and accurately inform your own manager(s) about the project's status, progress, challenges, and so on.
If you don't have that skill, you should focus on developing it if you want this role.
Or apply for a developer role, then during the interview say that you would be interested in growing into a project management role, which would give you a chance to understudy someone and learn the needed skills before trying to make that transition. Which is how most folks learn to manage projects.

Subjective question but going with the assumption you know what project management is, then the response is; You are the person responsible for getting that project completed on schedule, within budget and no issues are pending to finalize. Because the owners, investors, etc cannot be there, it is your job to report period progress on the major things that matter to the people that share the risk.  What, why, who, where and always, when!
